# ConTeXt: Disable emdash

Tags: fonts, context, punctuation, ligatures

## Background

Some manuscript submission guidelines prefer em dashes to remain typeset as `---` rather than `—`.

## Problem

Setting `features=none` for the document's body font does not appear to affect the `tlig` setting.

## SSCCE

The following code produces a document with an em dash:

```tex
\definefontfamily [FontFace] [rm] [TeX Gyre Pagella] [features=none]
\setupbodyfont    [FontFace]

\starttext
Why hello --- and how are you?
\stoptext
```

## Question

How do you prevent ConTeXt from changing `---` to an em dash and---equivalently---`--` to an en dash?

ConTeXt version 2021.04.29 23:09.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been recently discussed in the mailing list ([here the message by Hans](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg98162.html)).  You need `\nohyphencollapsing` which deals both with em-dash and en-dash:

```
\startTEXpage
{\nohyphencollapsing Why hello --- -- and how are you?}

{Why hello --- -- and how are you?}
\stopTEXpage
```

As a note, you have to update your ConTeXt distribution so that this feature is available.

[image]